Upload 1GB image on apache server
I want to upload a 1GB file on apache server.
I am using core php for file upload.
Server is getting timout on upload of 1GB file
Here are my server configuration:
upload_max_filesize = 1024M 

post_max_filesize = 1100M

max_execution_time = 86400

memory_limit = 1G

Tried various configuration, but didn't work.
Want to under if any other configuration changes are required.

Does this answer your question? 1GB file upload using php? Or 500 Internal Server Error - Unable to upload large video files using PHP?

@OlafKock No. The post shows not recommended approach.

Does your "1Gb" is actually less than "1024M"? Double all the numbers in config file, restart all services and try again

What you try to do with this 1Gb file? Maybe problem is not upload, but that you process it longer than 30s (default timeout)?

@Justinas Code Execution take more than 30s. Is that a problem? Please suggest some receommended solution

@GauravHiran Make request perform action in background. Use queues or just start another bash PHP CLI action to perform job and don't wait for response.

@Justinas The File upload is a laravel backend API. So how do i give response to the caller of an API?

@GauravHiran You don't. After processing is complete you can send email or caller should call some additional API calls to poll when job is completed.
